# How do you save an attribute to the database that is not coming from the form params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I am basically trying to save a key that I am generating in the model. It is not something the user is filling out in a form. I keep getting the error when I go to /model/new

```
undefined method `presentation_url=' for #<Class:0x007fc3c7d8ca38>
```

here is a general idea of what I am doing in the model.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :price, :pdf, :banner 
  self.presentation_url = "a generated url that is not coming from the form"
end
```

I already generated and ran the migration for the presentation_url attribute and checked to see that the column does exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback in your model, something like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :presentation_url

  attr_accessible :description, :name, :price, :pdf, :banner 

  def default_presentation_url
    self.presentation_url ||= "a generated url that is not coming from the form"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that the class `Product` has no method named `presenteation_url=`. The method should exist on instances of class `Product`, if it's made available by activerecord based on column name. Therefor you should use the method `presentation_url=` in some instance method and not at class level or class methods.